# C/C++ Check Digit

Tags: c

I'm writing a function to build a checksum from a given string.

The checksum is defined as:
  2’s complement of the 7 low order bits of the binary sum of all characters on a line preceding the checksum, including the STX and CR.

So far i've come up with:

```
CheckDigit = getcheckdigit(buffer);
sprintf(buffer,"%c%c%c%s%s%c%c",
        2,
        iDP,
        iStatus,
        my_ltoa(s,NetWeight,7,0x00),
        my_ltoa(t,TareWeight,6,0x00),
        13, 
        CheckDigit);

int getcheckdigit(char *buffer) {

    int checkdigit,i;
    int sum;
    char *ptr;

    for (i=0;i<=16;i++) {
        *ptr=buffer[i];
        sum = sum + atoi(ptr);      
    }

    sum = sum % 64;

    checkdigit = ~sum;
    checkdigit = checkdigit + 1;

    return checkdigit;
}
```

This seems to return the same value and i can't figure out why as i cant debug it.

Comment: Please read a book explaining you how to use pointers. You are doing it very wrong.

Comment: And when you say "binary sum of all characters" you mean the sum of the ASCII values? Then you don't need atoi. And what's STX?

Comment: **Q: what is `ptr`?** A: A pointer. **Q: Where does it point to?** A: I don't know. **Q: What are you writing to you don't know where?** A: the elements of `buffer`. ... :)

Comment: Careful...that assignment "*ptr=buffer[i];" is unsafe, given that you haven't allocated any memory for ptr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sum is not initialised.

You are deferencing an undefined pointer (ptr).

You don't need the atoi.

You are only using the bottom 6 bits.

Two's complement is just a negation (although your binary not and adding 1 should work).

Try:

```
int getcheckdigit(char *buffer) {

    int i;
    int sum = 0;

    for (i=0;i<=16;i++) {
        sum += buffer[i];
    }

    sum = -(sum % 128);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, haven't written c in years, and i couldn't debug as I am working in an embedded environment with no tools for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need atoi, just add `buffer[i]`.  atoi is interpreting a string as a number, something not wanted in this case, and you use it in a wrong way if it was wanted.